# sql - select quotes disable not null requirement

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

In my database, the column `cardid` has not null set to true i.e. null not allowed.

When I run the following query in a delphi cum zeos TZQuery, the result field `card_id0` has the property required as true which is correct but result field `card_id1` doesn't i.e. the quotation marks around `card_id1` seem to mean give me the data but without constraints.

```
select c.id, c.cardid as card_id0, c.cardid as "card_id1" 
  from mydata c
```

Is this standard in sql?

Comment: I don't think constraints on resultset/cursors are part of the sql standard at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a Delphi problem, not a MySQL problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing, is the TZQuery not detecting the database constraint (not null) from the table/query metadata.  This is only meaningful only if you add or update a record through the TZQuery component.  You will still get an exception if you try to add or update a record with a null for `card_id0` or `card_id1`.  The exception will be generated by the database rather than the component.

Typically, quoting of field names (or aliases) only serves to allow illegal characters in a field name in a SQL query, i. e., having a space in a field name.  There can be side effects to quoting field names, for example in Firebird/Interbase, quoting a field name will make it case sensitive while they are normally case insensitive.

Comment: this seems to be the correct answer (and the last sentence is very interesting). I'm using the constraints together with an inmemory table to ensure data is correct before trying to enter it into the database and thereby avoid raising exceptions. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is anything to do with sql, you don't get constraints back with a resulset.
I'd guess this is TZQuery. As a guess I'd say it went and got the meta data for the table C, assumed a map between cardid and cardid0, then had nothing for "card_id1".

Reverse the order the fields in the select clause, see if the required property swaps with it.

Comment: "dont get constraints back with a result set"! Ah, but I do 8=) because without the quotation marks, the result fields have the correct "required" value of false/true to match the "allow null" property in the database whereas the quotation marks always result in a false value

Comment: No you don't. TZquery is returning the result of the query, and to do that has a peer at the underlying database. Don't rely on it, how accurate it is depends on too many things.

Comment: Hmm, very valid point. Oh well, back to the drawing board. Thanks for stopping me before I got too far. Enjoy your weekend. Bill